# How to get href attribute value in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, attributes, web-crawler, casperjs

here is what I do with the code to get the href value inside a elements:

```
var info = this.getElementsInfo(selector); // an array of object literals
for (var i = firstp; i < info.length; i=i+interval) {
    if(i==0)
        this.echo('"'+info[i].getAttribute('href')+'"');
    else
        this.echo(',"'+info[i].getAttribute('href')+'"');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something in the [documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html) and I can solve my problem with code like this:

```
var info = this.getElementsInfo(selector); // an array of object literals
for (var i = firstp; i < info.length; i=i+interval) {
    if(i==0)
        this.echo('"'+info[i].attributes.href+'"');
    else
        this.echo(',"'+info[i].attributes.href+'"');
}
```

and it works now.

The reason it didn't work before with `getAttribute` is that [`casper.getElementsInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) returns a plain object representation of the DOM nodes and not the actual DOM nodes. As CasperJS (and PhantomJS for that matter) have two contexts, DOM nodes cannot be passed out of the page context (inside [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)).

Comment: It's ok. When you write an answer, it is always good to add a description why something is like it is. I added one for you with a broader theme.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

Get the path first

```
some variable = 'table#dgResults > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > b a';
```

it goes (this only an explanation of "some variable"):

```
table[id="dgResults"] -> (couldn't add to the stupid gray box)

    tbody

      tr-> lst column

          b
              a -> all href tags are here
```

Next use the the `getElementsAttribute`

```
var nextStep = this.getElementsAttribute(elem, 'href');
```

Then dump it:

```
utils.dump(nextStep);
```

You should see all the links when you dump it. Remember that `this.getElementAttribute()` returns 1 value between the tag and `this.getElementsAttribute()` returns ALL the values between the tags.